Script to add a horizontal line with alert and define it's properties by a user-selectable template
Every morning after I've created my watchlist, I review each chart and set horizontal lines for SUPPORT and RESISTANCE.  After laying down each line, I choose a template to define it's properties and then copy the name of that line to be used when I create an alert with the name of the line (e.g. SUPPORT or RESISTANCE).  This is pretty simple to do, but very repetitive.  I'd like to be able to write script to draw a horizontal line, provide user-selectable input from the templates, and apply an alert using the name defined in the associated template. Can it be done?
I'm new to Pine Scripts so I haven't tackled it yet, just looking for confirmation that it can be done.
